# vb.net passing Function as argument

Tags: .net, vb.net, arguments

I have a simple application, that run in remote desktop from pads.

The app is written in visual basic and it's structured like this:

- Main

  - Tab_01
  - Tab_02
  - and so forth

At present, when I call a print function from Tab_02 (for example), I do like this:

- Main.showWaitScreen()
- Tab_02.Print()
- Main.dismissWaitScreen()

What I what to do is to call the mainShowWaitScreen() passing as argument a function that, when done, automatically dismiss the wait screen.

I tried to pass the print function as ACT or FUNC like this:

```
Main.setWaitScreen(msg:="Printing...", action:=cr.print(printerName:=printer))
```

and in then Main.setWaitScreen:

```
Public Function setWaitScreen(ByVal msg As String, ByVal action As Action) As Boolean
    Try
        wait = New rrWait
        wait.setText(text:=msg)
        Me.Controls.Add(wait)
        wait.BringToFront()
        wait.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Me.Update()

        action()

        If Not wait Is Nothing Then
            wait.Parent = Nothing
            wait.Dispose()
            wait = Nothing
        End If

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name) : Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The problem is that the function act immediately, when I declare the argument, and not when the Main.setWaitScreen() call the function action().

Where is the mistake? How to solve it?

Thanks a lot.

Riccardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For passing functions as parameters in vb.net you can use `AddressOf` keyword.

```
Public Sub Execute(Action action)
    Console.WriteLine("Before")
    action()
    Console.WriteLine("After")
End

Public Sub MyAction()
    ' Do something
End Sub

' And call
Execute(AddressOf MyAction)
```

But because you passing printer as argument to the function you want to call later, you can not use `AddressOf`.

Instead wrap your method with anonymous action where printer is already given

```
Main.setWaitScreen(msg:= "Printing...", action:= Sub() cr.print(printerName:=printer))
```